# Java Reactor StepVerifier.withVirtualTime loop: repeatedly check with "expectNoEvent()", "expectNext()" and "thenAwait()"

Tags: java, reactor

I am learning Java 11 reactor. I have seen this example:

```
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(3600))
            .expectSubscription()
            .expectNextCount(3600);
```

This example just checks that with a `Flux<Long>` which increments 1 after every second till one hour, the final count is 3600.

But, is there any way to check the counter repeatedly after every second?

I know this:

```
.expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
.expectNext(0L)
.thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

But I have seen no way to repeatedly check this after every second, like:

```
.expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
.expectNext(i)
.thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
```

when `i` increments till 3600. Is there?

---

PS:
I tried to add `verifyComplete()` at last in a long-running tests and it will never end. Do I have to? Or just ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you wanted by using `expectNextSequence`. You have to pass an `Iterable` and include every element you expect to arrive. See my example below:

```
var longRange = LongStream.range(0, 3600)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

StepVerifier
    .withVirtualTime(() -> Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1)).take(3600))
    .expectSubscription()
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofHours(1))
    .expectNextSequence(longRange)
    .expectComplete().verify();
```

If you don't add `verifyComplete()` or `expectComplete().verify()` then the JUnit test won't wait until elements arrive from the flux and just terminate.

For further reference see the JavaDoc of `verify()`:

> this method will **block** until the stream has been terminated